# .net Reflector "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: .net, reflection, compact-framework, decompiler

I'm working with .net Reflector to view some .net Compact Framework .dlls and I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error for one of them.  I downloaded the trial version of 9Rays.Spices.Net and it loaded the .dll just fine.  The only problem is that I'm getting only every other method.

I was able to extract all of the MSIL from the assembly, but it's over 20,000 lines!  Is there any alternative to .net Reflector or an MSIL to C# translator?  Or does anyone know how to fix the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error?

Any help would be excellent :)

Comment: I think your best coures of action is to report the bug to RedGate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blah, I found that the DLL itself was corrupt.  Since Spices.Net is more robust, it knew how to handle it.  I just fixed the corruption in the DLL and everything worked great!

Comment: This suddenly felt like product placement.

Comment: It's not. I don't work for or am associated with Red Gate. Or Spices.